# Selecting a DIV ID that is Currently Visible and Storing in a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, switch-statement

How would you select the very first child of a parent ID that is currently visible and store it into a variable?

I've listed sample code below.  Which is a series of content that fades in and out when someone clicks or presses the enter key. I'm adding a button in the sidebar in case someone doesn't want to go through all of the steps (there's over 140 switch case statements in the real code) and wants to go directly to the contact form.  I'm stuck on how to select the currently visible ID so I can fade it out while the contact form fades in.

**SAMPLE HTML With Only the Immediate Child DIVs**

```
    <div id="page_container">
        <div id="page1"></div>
        <div id="page2"></div>
        <div id="page3"></div>
        <div id="submitPage"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="side_bar">
        <button id="submit_button">Click Here</button>
    </div>
```

**SAMPLE HTML**

```
<div id="page_container">
    <div id="page1" style="visibility: hidden">
        <div id="inner_page1">
            <div id="inner_page1_content">
                Page 1 Content goes here.
            </div>
            <button id="button_1">Click Here</button>
            <div id="click_1">press Enter</div>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div id="page2" style="visibility: hidden">
        <div id="inner_page2">
            <div id="inner_page2_content">
                Page 2 Content goes here.
            </div>
            <button id="button_2">Click Here</button>
            <div id="click_2">press Enter</div>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div id="page3" style="visibility: hidden">
        <div id="inner_page3">
            <div id="inner_page3_content">
                Page 3 Content goes here.
            </div>
            <button id="button_3">Click Here</button>
            <div id="click_3">press Enter</div>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div id="submitPage" style="visibility: hidden">
        <div id="inner_submitPage">
            <div id="inner_submitPage_content">
                Submit page Info Goes here.
            </div>
            <button id="button_4">Click Here</button>
            <div id="click_4">press Enter</div>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
<div id="side_bar">
    <button id="submit_button">Click Here</button>
</div>
```

**SAMPLE JQUERY**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function handleEvent(e){
        var id = null;          
        var fade_out;
        var fade_in;
        var the_variable = null;

        if (e.type === 'click'){
            id = $(this).attr("id");
        }else{
            id = e.which;
        }

        switch (id){
            case 13:
            if ($('#click_1').is(':visible')){
                fade_out = '#page1';
                fade_in  = '#page2';
            }
            if ($('#click_2').is(':visible')){
                fade_out = '#page2';
                fade_in  = '#page3';
            }
            if ($('#click_3').is(':visible')){
                fade_out = '#page3';
                fade_in  = '#submitPage';
            }
            if ($('#click_4').is(':visible')){
                fade_out = '#submitPage';
                fade_in  = '#page1';
            }
            break;
            case 'page1':
            fade_out ='#page1";
            fade_in  = '#page2";
            break;
            case 'page2':
            fade_out ='#page2";
            fade_in  = '#page3";
            break;
            case 'page3':
            fade_out ='#page3";
            fade_in  = '#submitPage";
            break;
            case 'submit_button':
             //something like below.....
             if $('#page_container'):first-child.is(':visible').(select child ID name){
                
                the_variable = ??child_id_name??;
                fade_out = the_variable;
                fade_in  = '#submitPage";
            }
            break;
        }

        $(fade_out).fadeTo( 'fast', 0 ).css('visibility','hidden').css('display','none');
        $(fade_in).delay( 800 ).css('visibility','visible').css('display','block').fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );
    }
    $('#ts_container').on('click', 'button, a', handleEvent);
    $(document).on('keypress', handleEvent);  
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could just add the very basic code to reproduce your issue, you may also consider adding a snippit of working code, this will help you get a favorable answer much faster.

Comment: Please see what is [mre]

Comment: Dale - https://jsfiddle.net/h574cwej/

Comment: ikiK - this is minimal if you look at the code in jsfiddle which still doesn't include it all.

Comment: It is hard to help in this case. Consider moving all the "rules" to a data structure like JSON instead of having all this information in switch/case statements. There is a lot of repeating code -- make use of a function instead. Consider using class names instead of setting properties directly on elements. Then maybe you can select the element that you need using a CSS selector.

Comment: Thx Chrwahl, I finally came up with a pretty simple solution. I understand the code isn't as optimized as it could be and I'm sure there are much better ways to do this. This is actually the 2nd iteration of it. The first was way worse and over twice the size that it is currently. However, I am still learning JS, and I only program once every blue moon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***How would you select the very first child of a parent ID that is currently visible and store it into a variable?***

You can use a conditional to check if your computed and/or inline styles for your first children, `divEl.children[0]`, are set to `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. If they are not then run code to define the id in a variable.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent')
const children = document.querySelectorAll('.child')
let id = '';
children.forEach(child => {
  child.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // comment out the following line to see differing results in assignment of ID in console
    e.target.children[0].classList.toggle('hide') //<-- using a classList toggle for displaying child element.
    let compStyleDisplay = getComputedStyle(e.target.children[0]).getPropertyValue('display')
    let compStyleVisibility = getComputedStyle(e.target.children[0]).getPropertyValue('visibility')
    // I am ONLY checking the CSS computedStyles for display and visibility, 
    // not the inline styles, also check if a child exists in the hidden div
    compStyleDisplay !== "none" && compStyleVisibility !== "hidden" && e.target.children[0].children[0] !== undefined ? id = e.target.children[0].children[0].id : id = 'non-existent';
    console.log(`first childs ID is: ${id}`)
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.id {
  background: yellow;
}

#sub1,
#sub2,
#sub3,
#sub4,
#sub5 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sub {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div class="child" id="1">some content
    <div class="hide" id="sub1">hidden div with one child
      <div class="sub" id="sub1-1">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
      <div class="sub" id="sub1-2">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="2">some content
    <div class="hide" id="sub2">hidden div with two children
      <div class="sub" id="sub2-1">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
      <div class="sub" id="sub2-2">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="3">some content
    <div class="hide" id="sub3">hidden div with three children
      <div class="sub" id="sub3-1">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
      <div class="sub" id="sub3-2">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
      <div class="sub" id="sub3-3">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="4">some content
    <div class="hide" id="sub4">hidden div with four children
      <div class="sub" id="sub4-1">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
      <div class="sub" id="sub4-2">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
      <div class="sub" id="sub4-3">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
      <div class="sub" id="sub4-4">This is some child content of a hidden div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="5">some content
    <div class="hide" id="sub5">Hidden div without children</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't account for keyboard events. I assume I would just repeat the code for the such with a few adjustments? Thank you for the thorough answer. I'll implement this strategy when I revise the code again. I've just now finally got it all working as it should with existing structure w/o any bugs   Example, the last two lines that handles keypresses and clicks was blocking all keyboard presses (couldn't fill out form fills) and all unassigned buttons and anchors .. but managed to fix that yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a solution. Maybe not the best one. But, it'll do for now until I learn how to do more advanced techniques that are less gibberish.

I added a new div ID wrapper for all of the content. Created a submit form wrapper outside of that content and then added a new case switch to fade out the main ID wrapper and fade in the secondary ID wrapper with the form when someone clicks the button.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="left_sidebar"></div>
  <div id="main_wrapper">
      <div id="content-1"></div>
      <div id="content-2"></div> + 100 More. 
  </div>
  <div id="contact_wrapper">
      <div id="contact_form2">
  </div>
  <div id="right_sidebar">
      <button id="button1">Click Here</div>
  </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
case: button1:
fade_out = '#main_wrapper';
fade_in = '#contact_wrapper';
break;
```